# $f$ is an automorphism and $f(5)=5$ then what are the possibilities for $f(1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $f$ is a map from $\mathbb{Z}_{20}\mapsto \mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Let us assume that $f$ is an group automorphism and $f(5)=5$ then what are the possibilities for $f(1)$?

Now first thing I know is that order of $f(1)$ should divide $20$. So possible orders of $f(1)$ are $1,2,4,5,10$

Also generator should go to generator so $f(1)$ can be $1, 3, 7, 9,11,13,17,19$

But I am not able to conclude anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(1)=x$, then we must have $5x\equiv 5$ mod $20$, i.e. $\frac{5x-5}{20}=\frac{x-1}{4}$ is an integer, i.e. $x$ divides $4$ gives remainder $1$. So $x=1, 5, 9, 13, 17$. Now $5$ cannot do since $f$ is an automorphism, so $x$ can be $1, 9, 13, 17$.